# jQuery mobile web page going out of the mobile screen

Tags: android, cordova, jquery-mobile, mobile, phonegap-build

Actually I am developing a phonegap android application using jQuery mobile 
in which I have designed a page which is going going out of the emulator and device screen. Please help I have searched but not understanding how to keep it within the boundaries of the phone.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Page Title</title>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<link rel="stylesheet"
    href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.3.0/jquery.mobile-1.3.0.min.css" />

<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
<script
    src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.3.0/jquery.mobile-1.3.0.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>

    <div data-role="page" id="device1">
        <div data-role="header" style="text-align: center;">Message one</div>
        <div data-role="content">
            <table width="100%" cellpadding="5" cellspacing="0" border="0">
                <tr>
                    <td align="left">InfodeepIndians</td>

                    <td align="right" colspan="2">3 Minutes ago</td>
                </tr>

                <tr>
                    <td colspan="3" align="justify">Samsung pioneered the trend of
                        a new breed of devices, now more commonly known as
                        'phablets',smartphones that are (almost) nearing tablets in size.</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td align="left">By panel.</td>
                    <td align="center">21.12%</td>
                    <td align="right">21 / 30</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td align="left" col><input type=text></td>
                    <td align="center"><input type=text></td>
                    <td align="right"><input type=text></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td align="left" col><input type=button value="Nos Limit"></td>
                    <td align="center"><input type=button value="% delivery"></td>
                    <td align="right"><input type="button" value="% match"></td>
                </tr>
            </table>


        </div>
        <div data-role="footer" style="text-align: center;">@Copyrights</div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Try `Layout gird` instead of tables. http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.2.0-beta.1/docs/content/content-grids.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace your table with jQuery flexible grid.

You can use current grid implementation and it will look like this: http://jsfiddle.net/Gajotres/xftPB/

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Page Title</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1"/>
<link rel="stylesheet"
    href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.3.0/jquery.mobile-1.3.0.min.css" />

<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
<script
    src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.3.0/jquery.mobile-1.3.0.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>

    <div data-role="page" id="device1">
        <div data-role="header" style="text-align: center;">Message one</div>
        <div data-role="content">
            <div class="ui-grid-b">
                <div class="ui-block-a">InfodeepIndians</div>
                <div class="ui-block-b"></div>
                <div class="ui-block-c" style="text-align: right;">3 Minutes ago</div>
            </div><!-- /grid-b -->
            <p style="text-align:justify;">Samsung pioneered the trend of
                        a new breed of devices, now more commonly known as
                        'phablets',smartphones that are (almost) nearing tablets in size.</p>
            <div class="ui-grid-b">
                <div class="ui-block-a">By panel.</div>
                <div class="ui-block-b">21.12%</div>
                <div class="ui-block-c">21 / 30</div>
            </div><!-- /grid-b -->            
            <div class="ui-grid-b">
                <div class="ui-block-a"><input type="text"></div>
                <div class="ui-block-b"><input type="text"></div>
                <div class="ui-block-c"><input type="text"></div>
            </div><!-- /grid-b -->
            <div class="ui-grid-b">
                <div class="ui-block-a"><input type=button value="Nos Limit"></div>
                <div class="ui-block-b"><input type=button value="% delivery"></div>
                <div class="ui-block-c"><input type="button" value="% match"></div>
            </div><!-- /grid-b -->            
        </div>
        <div data-role="footer" style="text-align: center;">@Copyrights</div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

In case you need better grid flexibility use this 3rd party grid implementation for jQuery Mobile: http://jeromeetienne.github.com/jquery-mobile-960/

Answer (score 0):

I have not compile the code but can you change the jquery version to jquery-1.7.1.min.js, Jquery 9 has so much changes. If correct please let me know

Answer (score 0):

Using [Grids](http://view.jquerymobile.com/1.3.0/docs/widgets/grids/) is more reliable than using `tables` in Jquery Mobile.

`ui-grid-b` consists of 3 columns.

Here is an example

```
<div class="ui-grid-b">
<!-- First row-->
      <div class="ui-block-a"><input type=text></div>
      <div class="ui-block-b"><input type=text></div>
      <div class="ui-block-c"><input type=text></div>
<!-- Second row-->
      <div class="ui-block-a"><input type=button value="Nos Limit"></div>
      <div class="ui-block-b"><input type=button value="% delivery"></div>
      <div class="ui-block-c"><input type="button" value="% match"></div>
</div>
```

JSfiddle: [Grids](http://jsfiddle.net/tJtbT/1/)